# Flutter:GestureDetector does not work in ListWheelScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I don't find the error why the on tab gesture is not called when you press one of the tiles. Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final List<Widget> questionThemes = <Widget>[];

for (int i = 0; i < numberQuestionBundels; i++) {
  questionThemes.add(GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        print('Does not work');
        //... Navigation Method
      });
    },
    child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: ListView(itemExtent: 20.0, children: <Widget>[
        Text('Thema: ' + lectionBundle.taskBundle[i].nameOfTask,
            style: textStyles.lightGrey20Creepy,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        //... more Texts
      ]),
    ),
  ));
}

return ListWheelScrollView(
  itemExtent: 110,
  diameterRatio: 5,
  children: questionThemes,
);}
```

Comment: I think I have a partial solution. The problem seems to be that the loop creates the widgets beforehand.
The same problem occurs when using a "GridView".
The "builder" method is available from "GridView". It is therefore possible to embed the loop logic here and everythink is working fine.
"ListWheelScrollView" doesn't seem to have a "builder" method yet.